# SQL query to get date pairs within id

Tags: mysql, sql, join, self-join

I have a table with the following rows:

```
    | item_id | change_type | change_date | change_id | other columns...
    | :------ | :---------- | :---------- | :-------- |
    |     123 |         off |  2019-06-04 |       321 |
    |     123 |          on |  2019-07-11 |       741 |
    |     123 |         off |  2019-07-13 |       987 |
    |     123 |          on |  2019-08-01 |       951 |
    |     123 |         off |  2019-08-07 |       357 |
    |     456 |         off |  2019-08-01 |       125 |
    |     456 |          on |  2019-11-18 |       878 |
    |     789 |          on |  2019-12-18 |       373 |
    |     012 |         off |  2019-12-25 |       654 |
    |     698 |         off |  2019-08-01 |       741 |
    |     698 |          on |  2018-01-03 |       147 |
```

I am trying to run a query which produces the following result:

```
    | item_id | on_date    | off_date   | on_id | off_id | other columns...
    | :------ | :--------- | :--------- | :---- | :----- |
    |     123 |            | 2019-06-04 |       |    321 |
    |     123 | 2019-07-11 | 2019-07-13 |   741 |    987 |
    |     123 | 2019-08-01 | 2019-08-07 |   951 |    357 |
    |     456 |            | 2019-08-01 |       |    125 |
    |     456 | 2019-11-18 |            |   878 |        |
    |     789 | 2019-12-18 |            |   373 |        |
    |     012 |            | 2019-12-25 |       |    654 |
    |     698 | 2018-01-03 | 2019-08-01 |   147 |    741 |
```

> The result I need is a table wherein the dates "on" and dates "off" are noted in decending order (grouped by `item_id`), with the "off" dates on the same row as the previous (in time) "on" date.

The closest I have gotten to are the following variations:

#### Attempt One:

```sql
SELECT
    changes_main.item_id,
    `on_date`,
    `off_date`,
    `on_id`,
    `off_id`
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT `item_id`
    FROM item_changes
) AS changes_main
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT
        `item_id`, -- for joining purposes only
        `change_date` AS `on_date`,
        `change_id` AS `on_id`
    FROM item_changes
    WHERE `change_type` = 'on'
) AS changes_ons ON changes_ons.item_id = changes_main.item_id
RIGHT OUTER JOIN ( -- although LEFT or RIGHT doesn't seem to matter
    SELECT
        `item_id`, -- for joining purposes only
        `change_date` AS `off_date`,
        `change_id` AS `off_id`
    FROM item_changes
    WHERE `change_type` = 'off'
) AS changes_offs ON changes_offs.item_id = changes_main.item_id
;
```

However, this essentially effectuates a `CROSS JOIN` between `on_date` and `off_date`.

The only variation in the second attempt is to add a `WHERE` clause. This was an idea I got from [this question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/24014/how-do-i-get-the-current-and-next-greater-value-in-one-select).

#### Attempt Two:

```sql
-- Same exact query as the above, however with the following
-- WHERE statement placed where the semicolon is above:
WHERE
    `off_date` = (
        SELECT MIN(offs2.change_date)
        FROM item_changes AS offs2
        WHERE offs2.change_type = 'off' AND
        offs2.change_date > changes_ons.on_date
    )
;
```

The problem with this is that where there is an un-even number of "on/off" in an item_id, that extra "on" or "off" get filtered out.

I have tried variation of the above `WHERE` clause including `OR off_date IS NULL`, `OR on_date IS NULL`, etc.

#### Update:

A third attempt was to use a `UNION` and some `SCALAR SUBQUERIES`. This was the closest I got to the result I need. However, is still falling short (for example, it doesn't include the `change_id`, along with not creating a perfect match).

```sql
SELECT
    changes_on.item_id,
    changes_on.change_date AS `on_date`,
    (SELECT MIN(offs2.change_date)
        FROM item_changes AS offs2
        WHERE offs2.change_type = 'off' AND
        offs2.change_date > changes_ons.change_date
    ) AS `off_date`,
    changes_on.change_id AS `on_id`,
    NULL AS `off_id` -- odd
FROM item_changes AS changes_on
WHERE `change_type` = 'on'

UNION

SELECT
    changes_offs.item_id,
    changes_offs.change_date AS `off_date`,
    (SELECT MIN(ons2.change_date)
        FROM item_changes AS ons2
        WHERE ons2.change_type = 'on' AND
        ons2.change_date < changes_offs.on_date
    ) AS `off_date`,
    NULL AS `on_id`, -- odd
    changes_offs.change_id AS `off_id`
FROM item_changes AS changes_offs
WHERE `change_type` = 'off'
;
```

Assistant / input / guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: Easy to do with window functions, available in MySQL 8.x. Are you using MySQL 5.x or 8.x?

Comment: Unfortunately 5.x. currently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assign a group based on the number of "on"s before each row.  Then use conditional aggregation:

```
select item_id,
       max(case when change_type = 'on' then date end) as on_date,
       max(case when change_type = 'on' then change_id end) as on_change_id,
       max(case when change_type = 'off' then date end) as off_date,
       max(case when change_type = 'off' then change_id end) as off_change_id
from (select t.*,
             sum(case when change_type = 'on' then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by item_id order by change_date) as grp
      from t
     ) t
group by item_id, grp;
```

EDIT:

In earlier versions of MySQL, you can express this as:

```
select item_id,
       max(case when change_type = 'on' then date end) as on_date,
       max(case when change_type = 'on' then change_id end) as on_change_id,
       max(case when change_type = 'off' then date end) as off_date,
       max(case when change_type = 'off' then change_id end) as off_change_id
from (select t.*,
             (select count(*)
              from t t2
              where t2.item_id = t.item_id and
                    t2.change_date <= t.change_date and
                    t2.change_type = 'on'
            ) as grp
      from t
     ) t
group by item_id, grp;
```

The performance will not be as good as using window functions, but an index on `(item_id, change_type, change_date)` would help.

Comment: Fantastic! Tks. I am using MySQL 5.x so I can't use `OVER` however I modified the `grp` query slightly to be a correlated subquery: `(SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN `change_type` = 'on' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) FROM t AS sub_t WHERE sub_t.item_id = t.item_id AND sub_t.change_date <= t.change_date) AS t` This by all test appears to be working, however I don't know if you are aware of any flaws with this `OVER` emulation?